# Looping through feed entries with rome

Tags: java, rome

I'm trying to loop through Atom feed entries, and get the title attribute lets say, I found [this](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/02/02/tour-of-rome.html) article, I tried this snipped of code  :

```
for (final Iterator iter = feeds.getEntries.iterator();
     iter.hasNext(); )
{
    element = (Element)iter.next();
    key = element.getAttributeValue("href");
    if ((key != null) &&
        (key.length() > 0))
    {
        marks.put(key, key);
    }

   //Don't have to put anything into map just syso title would be enough
}
```

But I get exception saying :

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntryImpl
>   cannot be cast to org.jdom.Element    at
>   com.emir.altantbh.FeedReader.main(FeedReader.java:47)

What did I do wrong? can anyone direct me towards better tutorial or show me where did I make mistake, I need to loop through entries and extract title tag value. thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`SyndFeed.getEntries()`](https://rome.dev.java.net/apidocs/0_8/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndFeed.html#getEntries%28%29) returns a `List` of `SyndEntryImpl`. You can not cast from `SyndEntryImpl` to `org.jdom.Element`.

You can iterate through all `SyndEntry` as follows:

```
for (final Iterator iter = feed.getEntries().iterator();
     iter.hasNext(); )
{
    final SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) iter.next();
    String title = entry.getTitle();
    String uri = entry.getUri();
    //...
}
```

#### API links

- [`com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry`](https://rome.dev.java.net/apidocs/0_8/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndEntry.html)
- [`com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed`](https://rome.dev.java.net/apidocs/0_8/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndFeed.html)
- [`java.util.List`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

---

You can also try this if you're using Java 5.0 and above:

```
for (SyndEntry entry : (List<SyndEntry>) feed.getEntries()) {
    String title = entry.getTitle();
    String uri = entry.getUri();
    //...
}
```

There is unchecked cast here, but it should be safe based on the specification of `getEntries()`.

#### See also

- [Java language guide/for-each loop](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
- [Java tutorials/generics](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

Comment: Great its working, but I have some custom tags inside <entry>, how do I get these? And I have a <content> and inisde that I have a another custom tag, how do I get these? One more thing, which approach is better(which one you recommend) iterator or generics

Comment: @gandalf: The choice is not iterator vs generics, but rather explicit iterator or implicit one in for-each. For-each, whenever applicable, is always better.

Comment: @gandalf: As to how to get the contents, go to the API links I gave above and look around. Try `System.out.println(entry.getContents());` and just experiment. I've never used Rome, all I know about it is what the documentation says.